# Add draggable fields to a form

Tags: 7, forms

I maintain a module (http://drupal.org/project/csm) that adds a new tab to the node type settings page, and gives the user various fields in that tab that can be used to tweak some settings related to that node type.

I'm in the process of adding some new functionality that will need me to change how this form works. I'll need to be able to give the user the ability to set an order of priority for some of the fields. So, if the fields are called A, B, C, D, and E, the user needs to be able to tell the form that C, say, is the most important field, followed by E, then D, then B, then A (for example).

I think the most elegant way to do this would be to allow the user to drag the fields about in the form, while they are typing into the fields. Is this possible with the Drupal form API? How can I do it?

Comment: Drupal has a tabledrag library built-in if that's what you mean? If you mean something different then you'll be looking at implementing the JS manually I would've thought

Comment: I don't think that's what I need. Essentially what I'm after is a way of making a series of text fields draggable, so the order can be changed and is then saved when the form is submitted.

Comment: Oh right, yeah Drupal has that built in - just add a multiple cardinality text field and you'll see that behaviour

Comment: Thanks! But doesn't that just define the number of values a field can hold? I've already got multiple fields defined (one per user user), and I want to be able to re-order these fields. Or should I just implement one field with multiple cardinality, and allow one value per user role that way?